# How to check if int[] array contains a value less than X?

Tags: postgresql

We can check if a specific value is contained in an array using `'X' = ANY(haystack)`. However, how do I check if an array of integers contains a value that is less than X?, e.g. I want to find all arrays that have at least one value lower than 100.

Comment: `ANY` works with arbitrary operators, not just `=`

Answer (score 8):

Don't know if this is the answer, but one way of doing this is to create a range and then check if they overlap, e.g.

```sql
int4range(0, 100, '[]') @> ANY(t2.ages)
```

This works in cases when dealing with finite numbers, but would not work if `ages` can contain any negative value.

Update: Never mind, it was just `100 >= ANY(t2.ages)`.